# How to evaluate the following complex limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I have to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt3i}{2}}\frac{z}{4z^2+3}$$

I know the limit doesn't exist. I tried proving it by letting: $$z = x +iy,\\y =\frac{\sqrt3i}{2} $$

And then evaluating the new limit for $$x\rightarrow0\_$$

and
$$x\rightarrow0_+$$

and hence show they do not equal one another. However, this approach didn't work since I got to 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0\_}\frac{x+i\sqrt3/2}{4x(x+i\sqrt3)}$$

and got stuck.

Could I get some help guys?

Edit: sorry if the formatting isn't that good. I'm still new to this site.

Comment: The expression has the form $c/0$ where $c\ne 0$. (And your development is wrong.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust So, if it's simply c/0, it's enough to say the limit doesn't exist without any other proof?

Comment: Yep, you are at a pole.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I either did not know or had completely forgotten about that. Thank you!

Comment: First thing when you meet a limit is to evaluate the function !

Comment: Sorry, your development wasn't wrong, my bad. You are not stuck, when $x\to0$, your expression $\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We can represent the expression as
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt3i}{2}}\frac{z}{4z^2+3}
=\lim_{z\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}}\frac{z}{4\left(z+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)\left(z-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)}
\end{align*}

We observe $\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ is a pole of first order of $\frac{z}{4z^2+3}$ and so the limit does not exist.